# Jenkins Junit Custom element

Tags: xml, xslt, jenkins, junit, jenkins-plugins

I am looking at Jenkins to automate an accessibility report for me. The report returns results as pass, error, warning, notice, skipped.

When i look at a junit xml file, it only recognizes passed, error, failure and skipped. How would i go about adding custom elements such as warning and/or notice?

It doesn't have to be JUnit, i just need a plugin that let's me set the threshold for each, outputs the results and uploads my report files.  Any tips/suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

I did a lot of searching and i couldn't find a compatible plugin, not a tutorial on how to add custom elements so Jenkins would recognize them.

```xml
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="My Accessibility Report" tests="4" failures="1" warnings="1">
            <testcase name="T1" classname="MyAccessibilityReport.Test>
                    <error>Some error</error>
            </testcase>
            <testcase name="T2" classname="MyAccessibilityReport.Test/>
            <testcase name="T3" classname="MyAccessibilityReport.Test/>
            <testcase name="T2" classname="MyAccessibilityReport.Test>
                    <warning>Some warning</warning>
            </testcase>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

JUnit doesn't recognize my warning element in the xml and i am wondering how to make it recognize it in the simplest way possible. Thank you!

Comment: Did you figure this one out?

Answer (score 0):

seems there is a lot of interest in junit plugin customization - there are 247 forks as of the time of this response.

as of this date, I am in a team which posts xml and junit plugin posts elements as headed sections on a page for elements system-out and system-err, I dont know if this is custom or on master. I just tried to add a custom element, since I don't want to dump logs to stdout, summary-log-call was the element and the jenkins page ignored it.